# How to register keypress?

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I've made a popup div that shows a video if you press a button. If you press Esc, the div is hidden again and the video is removed. (Using JWPlayer in Flash.)

If you click on the JWPlayer video, Flash gets the focus and JavaScript can't listen for keypresses on the document anymore. Is it possible to make JavaScript get the focus after you've interacted with the JWPlayer video player, so that you can still press the Esc button after for example pausing the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, once focus is given to flash, the only way to get keypresses back is to click somewhere else.

This happens because flash is under a completely different process, it is responsible for everything within its '*window*' and it doesn't bubble its own events back to JS

Comment: Hmm, there has to be some way implemented into JWPlayer  I suppose? You can use jwplayer().play() to give input and jwplayer().getVolume to get output.. Why not give up the focus?

Comment: Oh, in Internet Explorer this is not a problem. You can interact with JW Player and still the Escape key works..

Comment: Flash and JS can interact. The problem is that by default, Flash does not bubble up the events, JW player could relay its events to the containing node if it chose to. Note that the browser itself still catches the events, so things like ctrl+t, alt+f4 still work, but you couldn't catch it in JS.

Comment: Mm, I sent a request to the JWP dev-team :)